# Redux Toolkit: state showing as Proxy / [[Handler]]: null, [[Target]]: null, [[IsRevoked]]:true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to react and following a tutorial. whenever i am deleting a product it shows in console that `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.userProducts.filter is not a function`

and when i am logging state.products or state.userProducts is saying

```
[[Handler]]: null,
[[Target]]: null,
[[IsRevoked]]:true
```

here is my productSlice.js file

```
const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState: {
    product: {},
    products: [],
    userProducts: [],
    error: '',
    loading: false,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [createProduct.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [createProduct.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.products = [action.payload];
    },
    [createProduct.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [getProducts.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProducts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.products = action.payload;
    },
    [getProducts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [getProduct.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProduct.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.product = action.payload;
    },
    [getProduct.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [getProductsByAdmin.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProductsByAdmin.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.userProducts = action.payload;
    },
    [getProductsByAdmin.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [deleteProduct.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [deleteProduct.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      const {
        arg: { id },
      } = action.meta;
       if (id) {
        state.userProducts = state.userProducts.filter(
           item => item._id != id
         );
         state.Products = state.Products.filter(
           item => item._id != id
        );
      }
    },
    [deleteProduct.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

and here is my dashboard file and one more its deletes the data from mongodb but its not filtering when click but when i refresh the page it works
here is my dashboard file

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user } = useSelector(state => ({
    ...state.auth,
  }));
  const { userProducts, loading } = useSelector(state => ({
    ...state.products,
  }));
  const userId = user?.result?._id;
  const adminProduct = userProducts.userProducts;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
      dispatch(getProductsByAdmin(userId));
    }
  }, [userId]);

  const handleDelete = id => {
    dispatch(deleteProduct({ id, toast }));
  };
```

getsProductByAdmin

```
export const getProductsByAdmin = createAsyncThunk(
  'products/getProductsByAdmin',
  async (userId, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const rData = await API.get(
        `http://localhost:---/----/----/${userId}` //userID
      ).then(res => {
        return res.data;
      });
      return rData;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? How else can I set the state?

Cheers.

Comment: Could you share `getProductsByAdmin`? Are you sure that when you call `getProductsByAdmin.fulfilled` that it's passed an array and not `null`?

Comment: thanks for feedback. i have included the getProductsByAdmin btw it's already getting deleted when i refresh the page the product is no more but doesn't re-render due to state.products.filter not working

Comment: oh, is it `state.products.filter()` that's not working or is it `state.userProducts.filter()`? One thing that I see is `state.Products.filter()` won't work as `state.Products` doesn't have a value in it (capital as `Products` with a capital `P` isn't a property in your state object), it would need to be `state.products.filter()`

Comment: thanks nick for pointing out the silly mistake but it's still showing `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.userProducts.filter is not a function` and it's heppening only to userProducts do you have any idea where i am getting it wrong

Comment: hey nick thanks for the help actually I was not getting the array rather an object

Answer (score 0):

So Immer is something like JSON.stringify with Objects to basically decode Redux
State here instead of Objects that aren't stringified.

So basically do:

```
  import { original } from 'immer'
    
  console.log(original(state.products))
```

(Make sure you do npm i immer)

Answer (score 0):

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values

> It's very common for a developer to call `console.log(state)` during the development process. However, browsers display Proxies in a format that is hard to read, which can make console logging of Immer-based state difficult.

> When using either `createSlice` or `createReducer`, you may use the [current](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current) utility that we re-export from the [immer library](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/current/). This utility creates a separate plain copy of the current Immer
> `Draft` state value, which can then be logged for viewing as normal.

> It achieves this by taking a snapshot of the current state of a draft and finalizes it (but without freezing). Current is a great utility to print the current state during debugging, and the output of `current` can also be safely leaked outside the producer.

```js
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [{ id: 1, title: 'Example todo' }],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      console.log('before', current(state))
      state.push(action.payload)
      console.log('after', current(state))
    },
  },
})
```